# Bitcoin Block Header - Double SHA256 doesn't work

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, bitcoin

I have the following java-code:

```
public class DoubleSHA256 {

    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    public static String gen(String input) {

        MessageDigest digester = null;
        try {
            digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bytesToHex(digester.digest(digester.digest(input.getBytes())));

    }

    private static String bytesToHex(final byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];

        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }

        return new String(hexChars);
    }

}
```

The call of the class looks as following:

```
System.out.println(DoubleSHA256.gen(
    "0100000081cd02ab7e569e8bcd9317e2fe99f2de44d49ab2b8851ba4a308000000000000e320b6c2fffc8d750423db8b1eb942ae710e951ed797f7affc8892b0f1fc122bc7f5d74df2b9441a42a14695"
));
```

The result is:

```
6500f13bc254c59e9f3d77bd0b1999e686fadf7765ae2b59266d1d835b869083
```

but it should be:

```
1dbd981fe6985776b644b173a4d0385ddc1aa2a829688d1e0000000000000000
```

or

```
00000000000000001e8d6829a8a21adc5d38d0a473b144b6765798e61f98bd1d
```

Source (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm):

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> header_hex = ("01000000" +
    "81cd02ab7e569e8bcd9317e2fe99f2de44d49ab2b8851ba4a308000000000000" +
    "e320b6c2fffc8d750423db8b1eb942ae710e951ed797f7affc8892b0f1fc122b" +
    "c7f5d74d" +
    "f2b9441a" +
    "42a14695")
>>> header_bin = header_hex.decode('hex')
>>> hash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(header_bin).digest()).digest()

>>> hash.encode('hex_codec')
'1dbd981fe6985776b644b173a4d0385ddc1aa2a829688d1e0000000000000000'
>>> hash[::-1].encode('hex_codec')
'00000000000000001e8d6829a8a21adc5d38d0a473b144b6765798e61f98bd1d'
```

Can anyone give me a hint what is wrong?

Comment: The first thing I would be suspicious of is the raw `getBytes()` call without specifying a `Charset` indicating the encoding used.

Comment: The example data you are using is in hex. You converted the output *to* hex, but you also need to convert the input *from* hex, as the python code did.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: First, thank you for your fast response. Can you please specify what you mean with "the input from hex"?

Comment: The python example creates a string containing hex data named `header_hex` and then does `.decode('hex')` to decode it to "binary" `header_bin`. It then double-hashes the *binary* data, and displays the result back in hex. You need to do the Java equivalent, which is decode the input from hex, i.e. convert each two hex characters in the String to one byte in a byte array, the opposite of what you currently do in `bytesToHex` to encode the output.

Answer (score 1):

Cryptographic hashes return bytes, not hexadecimals. Hex is just a way of making the output human readable. So you first need to decode your hexadecimal input, and then encode the output - *if* you need the value in hexadecimals, that is. The double hash itself however should be void from encoding / decoding.

So you get:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class DoubleSHA256 {

    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    public static byte[] gen(byte[] input) {

        MessageDigest digester = null;
        try {
            digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return digester.digest(digester.digest(input));
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(final byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];

        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }

        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(bytesToHex(gen(Hex.decode("0100000081cd02ab7e569e8bcd9317e2fe99f2de44d49ab2b8851ba4a308000000000000e320b6c2fffc8d750423db8b1eb942ae710e951ed797f7affc8892b0f1fc122bc7f5d74df2b9441a42a14695"))));
    }
}
```

output:

```
1dbd981fe6985776b644b173a4d0385ddc1aa2a829688d1e0000000000000000
```

I'll leave it up to you to implement the hexadecimal decoder and the reversal *of the byte array*. Or you can use any available online coder like the one of Apache Commons Codec, Bouncy Castle, Guava etc. etc. etc.